# Скриншот определённой области.

Tags: c#, webbrowser

Здравствуй, ХешКод, скажите вот у меня есть елемент webBrowser1, там идёт загрузка сайта, а после чего идёт сриншот определённых координат, например сделать скрин, только одного поля Логина, и т.д Как такое реализовать? Искал в гугле, но мне выдали только как сделать скрин экрана, а про елементы не писали.

Answer (score 1):

Вы просто разберитесь, как делается скрин экрана. Вам нужно просто подставить в метод получения скриншота не координаты экрана, а экранные координаты интересующего Вас контрола.

Comment: Да но контрол имеент св-во Visible = false;

Comment: Так бы сразу и сказали. Можно попробовать вызвать его метод OnPaint.